# Requiring argument to be an instance of a (sub)class of a given class in typescript

Tags: typescript

The following compiles without error in TypeScript

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract talk() : string ;
}

class Chicken extends Animal {
    talk() : string { return "cluck" ; }
}

class Duck extends Animal {
    talk() : string { return "quack" ; }
}

function quack( d : Duck ) {
    console.log( d.talk() ) ;
}

var a = new Chicken() ;  // EDIT: `var a : Chicken = new Chicken()` gives the same result

quack( a ) ;
```

What I would like to do is to change the definitions `Chicken` and `Duck`  or maybe `quack` in a way such that `quack(a)` has a compile time error.  I.e. parameter `d` of type `Duck` should not be able to hold `Chicken`s nor any other objects that aren't direct or indirect instances of `Duck`.  I know that I can add unique properties to `Chicken` and `Duck` to distinguish them. E.g.

```
class Duck extends Animal {
    onlyInDuck : string ;
    talk() : string { return "quack" ; }
}

class Chicken extends Animal {
    onlyInChicken : string ;
    talk() : string { return "cluck" ; }
}
```

But this seems like a crude hack.

Is there an elegant way to require that a function argument be an instance of a (sub)class of the parameter type?

Comment: Chickens may walk like Ducks, but they don't talk like Ducks.

Comment: Try this: var a: Chicken = new Chicken() ; this will force 'a' to be of type Chicken.

Comment: @Delta Declaring the type of `a` to be `Chicken` doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong here, but I'm guessing probably not.  This appears to be by design to make the TypeScript language easier to interop with existing JavaScript code, as well as to embrace the dynamic nature of the language.

More specifically, since JavaScript (and by extension, TypeScript) doesn't actually have "types" (in the classical sense), the TypeScript compiler is more concerned about whether or not a particular instance adheres to a particular interface, with the same properties, functions, etc. as opposed to whether or not it was created using a particular constructor.

For your sake, I hope I'm wrong, but it wouldn't surprise me either way.

Comment: Yes you are right.  It's a feature not a bug. Typescript uses static duck typing. The question is not "why is my code compiling?" And it's not "Why is Typescript not more like Java programmers would expect?" The question is: what is the most elegant way to rewrite my code so it doesn't compile in the cases the argument is not an instance of the parameter type but does compile otherwise?

Comment: The solution you have posted is indeed the most elegant.